# Как исправить ошибку? "error: failed to push some refs"

Tags: bitbucket, git

Ни с того ни с сего начало выдавать ошибку

```
$ git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to https://[name]@bitbucket.org/[teamname]/[projectname].git
To https://[name]@bitbucket.org/[teamname]/[projectname].git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[name]@bitbucket.org/[teamname]/[projectname].git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: > the remote contains work that you do not have locally. 

= удаленный репозиторий имеет коммиты, которых нет на локальной машине

> You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

= вам бы их слить через git pull для начала

Answer (score 4):

Копирую предложение Etki: в таком случае нужно сделать `git pull`

> the remote contains work that you do not have locally.
>   You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Это значит:

> удаленный репозиторий имеет коммиты, которых нет на локальной машине
>   вам бы их **слить через git pull** для начала

Answer (score 1):

Была аналогичная ситуация с пушем на `Bitbucket`.

Перед этим делал `merge` c `my_branch` на `master`. `AndroidStudio` предложила пофиксить конфликтные файлы. Как и полагается, открыл вкладку `Version Control -> LocalChanges` и поисправлял все конфликты в файлах которые были отмечены красным цветом.
Но запушить на `origin master` так и не получилось.

Попробовал `git pull` - но результата проблема не решилась.

Вариант того что кто-то запушил код до меня на `origin master` - исключен, так как с кодом никто кроме меня не работал уже почти год. Так что вариант, что у меня на локалке  чего-то не хватает и нужно делать `git pull` - пришлось отбросить.

Сложно вспомнить на каком этапе я додумался проверить файлы в папке `.idea` текущего проекта. Но, в файле **`misc.xml`**  нашелся конфликтный участок типа:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD  
код из первой ветки
======
код из второй ветки  
>>>>>>> my_branch.
```

Удалил ненужные строки и метки.
Пересобрал проект и только после этого удалось запушить на удаленный сервер.
Почему  `misc` не был отмечен красным как файл с конфликтом - непонятно, возможно баг студии.